# TypeError: store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_.default.getStat is not a function

Tags: redux

Any idea about this error?

```
TypeError: store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_.default.getStat is not a function
```

I'm not sure about webpack requirement, as I understand all dependencies should be taken care by `create-react-app`

**store.js:**

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'; import freezerReducer from './reducers/freezer'; export default createStore (freezerReducer);

index.js: import store from './store'; console.log(store.getStat())
```

jest is passing all the tests though.

Thanks
Shan

Comment: shouldn't it be `store.getState()`?

Comment: i merged all files duck pattern.. its ok now.. thanks...